# c++ Access list inside struct

Tags: c++

```
struct nodepoint
    {
        bool State_ON;
        double xxx;
        double yyy;
        list<float> P;


       // node *next;
    }node [numMS];

list <nodepoint> eventlist;
```

=========================

how to access list of P list inside eventlist above?

for example if I want to print all elements in P list.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Working with `std::list` to access items, you can use iterators. For example:

C++11:

```
auto itr = eventlist.begin();

for (auto x : itr->P)
    cout << x << endl;
```

Before C++11:

```
list<nodepoint>::iterator itr = eventlist.begin();

for (list<float>::iterator itr2 = itr->P.begin(); itr2 != itr->P.end(); itr2++)
   cout << *itr2 << endl;
```

I assumed the lists are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
eventlist.back().P.back();
```

or

```
eventlist.back().P.front();
```

or

```
eventlist.front().P.front();
```

or

```
eventlist.front().P.back();
```

or

```
for ( nodepoint &nd : eventlist )
{
   for ( float x : nd.P ) std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Or you can use iterators that to get access to an element in the middle of a list.